# Authentication for the Office365 account for access in docs

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I have a `.NET` application in `C#` to send files to various `Office365` services, for example: `OneDrive`, `Email`, `Word`, etc. I found the "Authentication with OAuth" article on the MSDN site but I was unsure whether my application fits the purpose of this article.

In case, I will make the user log in to their `Office365` account, and so I can create access keys for `OneDrive`, `Email` and etc or what?

And in addition, at the end of the article is shown the `XML` code to inform the `AuthenticationToken`, but this can not be done throughout my code in `C#` normally?

Article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bing-ads-user-authentication-oauth-guide.aspx#registerapplication

Comment: Firstly, ouch those **bolds**. But to get to your question, it's sort of difficult to know what you want here. What do you mean by "send files"?

Comment: In my application I want to send files to OneDrive, for example. Previously I did with the google spreadsheets, creating a spreadsheet in the user account.

Comment: Files = docs, excel, word....